# Jenkins doesn't recognize tests of gradle subprojects

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I've got a gradle project with following setup:

- Project (actually only a project with settings.gradle)

  - Subproject A
  - Subproject B
  - Subproject C

My problem is now that jenkins test result analyzer doesn't recognize the tests. Where I have to set them so jenkins knows there are tests in the subprojects? 
The tests are JUNIT Tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by myself now. I forgot to set the pattern for the xml pahts in the JUNIT Plugin. =/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a task to grade.properties to execute test in a particular folder

```
task loadSubprojectATest(type:Exec) {
    workingDir 'SubprojectA/src/test/java'
    doFirst{
          -- whatever you need to execute goes here
    }
    doLast {
        print 'loadSubprojectATest task ending!\n'
    }
}
```

or you can add it to source sets

Comment: ok, that's sounds good. But I don't know how to execute the tests in this script. How can I excecute the tests? Usually the tasks are automatically executed during a build.